# Javascript Add two days to current date exclude holidays and weekends using date-fns library

Tags: javascript, datepicker, calendar, date-fns, react-day-picker

Suppose today is my current date I want to add two business days and if the holidays/weekends fall into these days , we append those many holidays and skip the weekends. 11/05/2022 + 2 days = 13/05/2022, if any holidays fall in between these days we move to next workin day ex: 12th is holiday then 14/02/2020 will be my payment date. Ex: if 13/05/2022 is Saturday or Sunday we skip and move to next working day 15/05/2022 is my payment date.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.